# sqlite: can i do select statement while looping through another select statement

Tags: iphone, sqlite

In my iPhone app, I use a sqlite table to hold my data. While I'm looping through a select statement on one of the tables, I want to do another select (and update) statement on the same table in some conditions. It's pretty complicated to explain why I would want to do this, but I'm pretty sure I need to.

The problem is that when I loop through the outer while loop, if I call the inner select statement, it terminates the outer loop after that run, even if it has more rows in the sql statement. So is this impossible? Can I call a select statement while I'm looping through the sqlite3_step results on the same table?
Here's some psuedo-code (in objective-c) to explain what I'm doing:

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0); // Begin Transaction

    if (init_all_statement == nil)
    {
        const char *sql = "SELECT id, fullname FROM contact";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_all_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error Test.m: failed with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    while (sqlite3_step(init_all_statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        ...

        if (blah) 
        {
            if (get_duplicate_rows == nil)
            {
                const char *sql = "SELECT id, fullname FROM contact where fullname = ?";

                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &get_duplicate_rows, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error Test.m: failed with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }
            }

            sqlite3_bind_text(get_duplicate_rows, 1, [contact_fullname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            while (sqlite3_step(get_duplicate_rows) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                ...
            }
            sqlite3_reset(get_one_row);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you only need to create a new statement to receive the new results

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
```

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: That's exactly what I do. get_duplicate_rows is a sqlite3_stmt

Comment: So, you are able to do what you want. Have you tried the psuedo-code that you put in your question?

Comment: I had tried it out before. Turns out, the problem was with something else. Thanks anyways.